# I have a script that gives an output on the screen and puts that data in a logfile but i want that data in another format. How can i do this?

Tags: bash, logging, linux-mint

I have this script that shows output on the screen every period of time and also saves it in a log.txt file. But i want the way it is saved in my log.txt file in a different way.

**My script is this:**

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2
  3 while [ 1 ]
  4 do
  5 echo "Downloadspeed in Mbps:"
  6 speedtest-cli --simple | grep Download | awk '{print $2}' | tee -a log.txt
  7 echo "TIJD:"
  8 date "+%T" | tee -a log.txt
  9 echo "DATUM:"
 10 date "+%D" | tee -a log.txt
 11 echo ""
 12 sleep $1m
 13 done
```

**An example log.txt looks like this:**

```
46.91
01:46:40
12/28/18
41.84
01:48:04
12/28/18
43.65
01:49:25
12/28/18
```

**But i want it to look like this:**

```
12/28/18 01:46:40 ,46.91            
12/28/18 01:48:04 ,41.84        
12/28/18 01:49:25 ,43.65
```

Can someone help me rewrite my script to get the other format in my log.txt file?

Greetings

Thomas Van Haute

Comment: Don't pipe `grep` to `awk`.  Instead, write `awk '/Download/{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

Since how you are generating output file is not clear to me, so as per your request working on output file to get expected output only and considering that your shown sample is how Input_file looks like.

```
awk '++count==1{val1=$0;next}  ++count==2{val2=$0;next} ++count==3{print $0,val1" ,"val2;val1=val2=count=""}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just introduce some variables and format your output accordingly.

This should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ] 
do
    the_speed=`speedtest-cli --simple | grep Download | awk '{print $2}'`
    the_date=`date "+%D"`
    the_time=`date "+%T"`

    echo "Download speed in Mbps: $the_speed"
    echo "Date: $the_date"
    echo "Time: $the_time"
    echo ""

    echo "$the_date $the_time, $the_speed" >> log.txt

    sleep $1m 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite tricks (and I've been doing this too long) is using xargs -L  to combine multiple lines into one.

I'll start with the final answer and I'll show you how I got there:

```
tail -r log.txt | xargs -L3 | tail -r | awk '{ print $1 , $2, ","  $3 }'
```

Well, let's just start with xargs -L3:

```
xargs -L3 <log.txt
```

The above yields something close to what you want:

```
$ xargs -L3 <log.txt
46.91 01:46:40 12/28/18
41.84 01:48:04 12/28/18
43.65 01:49:25 12/28/18
```

Clearly, the order of the columns is wrong.  So let's reverse the file first:

```
$ tail -r < log.txt
12/28/18
01:49:25
43.65
12/28/18
01:48:04
41.84
12/28/18
01:46:40
46.91
```

Now the file is reversed, let's pipe it through xargs again:

```
$ tail -r < log.txt | xargs -L3 
12/28/18 01:49:25 43.65
12/28/18 01:48:04 41.84
12/28/18 01:46:40 46.91
```

As you can see above, the columns in the right order, but the lines are reversed.  Let's just use the tail -r command again to reverse the file:

```
$ tail -r < log.txt | xargs -L3  | tail -r
12/28/18 01:46:40 46.91
12/28/18 01:48:04 41.84
12/28/18 01:49:25 43.65
```

Now the result is in the right order, but we are missing the comma (,).  We can put that in with awk or sed.  I like awk:

```
$ tail -r < log.txt | xargs -L3  | tail -r | awk '{ print $1 , $2, ","  $3 }'
12/28/18 01:46:40 ,46.91
12/28/18 01:48:04 ,41.84
12/28/18 01:49:25 ,43.65
```

But if you are sed fan, you can try it this way:

```
$ tail -r < log.txt | xargs -L3  | tail -r | sed 's/:.. /&,/'
12/28/18 01:46:40 ,46.91
12/28/18 01:48:04 ,41.84
12/28/18 01:49:25 ,43.65
```

The above command is simple enough, but it will only work if you have an input that ends.  That is, 'tail -r' doesn't work if the input stream is continuous, because it needs to read to the EOF before it can reverse the input.  So, this command I've given you is really only useful if you break out of your loop and post process the log.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` might work for you:

```
$ awk '{a[NR%3]=$0}NR%3==0{print a[0] " " a[2] " ," a[1]}' file
12/28/18 01:46:40 ,46.91
12/28/18 01:48:04 ,41.84
12/28/18 01:49:25 ,43.65
```

Possible `sed` solution:

```
$ sed -E 'N;N;s/(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)/\3 \2 ,\1/' file
12/28/18 01:46:40 ,46.91
12/28/18 01:48:04 ,41.84
12/28/18 01:49:25 ,43.65
```